# What's the role of 曾经 in 他曾经在北京学过两年汉语?

Tags: past-tense

In this sentence:

> 他曾经在北京学过两年汉语。

what's the role of 曾经? I understand that 过 already implies that the action happened in the past.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

曾经 is more equivalent to "once" in English as in the sentence

> Once we were the best friends.

It is used to:

> 1. express the fact the sentence is talking about happened in the past.
> 2. if the predicate verb is a durative verb*, express that fact can't be experienced(经=experience) by the speaker(doesn't last) any more. 
>    , the speaker implies that the status is different now. In this case, it means "used to" as in the sentence "*I used to be a kind man(implies now I am not)*." For your example, the speaker implies that he is not studying Chinese in Bejing now.

*By "durative verb", I mean the action expreesed by that verb can last for a long time. For example, "study, like, look, be, work,feed, etc.". These verbs can be used in the progress tense in English(-ing form). Some other verbs can not, such as "hear of, see, kick, etc." You can't say " I am hearing of a terrible story", while you can say" I am listening to a terrible story".

Can someone tell me the right grammar term if I am wrong?

Comment: +1... speaking as someone who knows quite a bit about english grammar, that's a hard question you pose there. *why not ask on the english site?*

Answer (score 2):

Just as 已经 means "already" and emphasizes the sense of the completed action particle 了, 曾经 means "once" and emphasizes the sense of 过. I disagree with Bob that 曾经 means already here; in general "once" or "ever" is a better translation. I would render your sentence as "I once studied two years of Chinese in Beijing."

Answer (score 0):

It means 'already', to add emphasis to the sentence - 'he already studied Mandarin in Beijing for two years'

Comment: So is it equivalent to 已经 in that sentence?

Comment: @dusan could you please propose a new question to know the difference between them?

Comment: @Huang done: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/902/13

Comment: @dusan I have completed my answer. 我已经完成了答案(here, I won't say 曾经)

Comment: Bob, could you please improve your answer? Post a translation of your example, or provide more examples.